# open page automatically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially, all I want to do is open an external web page after the current page is loaded via java script.

`open my page -> javascript tells browser to open external page -> external page being loaded into the broser`

How may I accomplish this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you may use this

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
    window.location.href = "http://externalpage.com";

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="load()">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
        window.location.href = "http://externalpage.com";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it should be window.location. Check the code.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can:

```
location.href = "http://example.net/";
```

… but you should perform an HTTP redirect instead as that is more reliable, faster and better food for search engines.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the "open" method to open the source file or url on a new window.

```
window.open("anyfile.*");
```

or

```
window.open("http://anylocation.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try this code for page loading time we will redirect whatever u configured the urls.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
   window.open('https://google.com');
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<script>
document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="https://www.google.com/" style="display: none;" id="link">Link</a>';
document.getElementById("link").click();
</script>
<body>
```