# how to make <a> html tag as default

Tags: html

There are 3 links.I want to make one link as default means it should automatically open after loading the page

```
<a href="addobe27.php">Create OBE</a>
  <a href="addco27selection.php">Add CO</a>
  <a href="addpo27selection1.php">Add PO</a>
```

I want to make add co as default.How?

Comment: you can not do it through html. need js for that

Comment: Why bother giving the user a page with three choices on it if you are immediately going to pick a choice for them and go to another page? This sounds like a job much better suited to an HTTP redirect combined with the deletion of the page with the three links.

Comment: If I understand correctly It has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029881/open-page-automatically-using-javascript Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="openPage()">

    <a href="test4.php" id="def"></a>
    <a href="test5.php" ></a>
    <a href="test6.php" ></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openPage(){
    defaultLink=document.getElementById("def");
    defaultLink=defaultLink.getAttribute("href");
       window.location.href=defaultLink;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```